# How to move elements up and down in asp.net datagrid with the help up of buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid

Here the issue is when I click up arrow on the first element the gridheader comes down and the 1st message goes to the top which is not required.
Similarly with with footer too... I took the help from some site.....

```
JS:
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MoveUp = "table[id*=dg] input[id*='btnUp']";
    var MoveDown = "table[id*=dg] input[id*='btnDown']";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        DisableLastFirstRow();
        $(MoveUp).click(function() {
            $(this).parents("tr").insertBefore($(this).parents("tr").prev());
            SetIndex();
            DisableLastFirstRow();
        });
        $(MoveDown).click(function() {
            $(this).parents("tr").insertAfter($(this).parents("tr").next());
            SetIndex();
            DisableLastFirstRow();
        });
        function DisableLastFirstRow() {
            $("#<%=dg.ClientID%> tr:has(td) input[id*='btnUp']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#<%=dg.ClientID%> tr:has(td):first input[id*='btnUp']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#<%=dg.ClientID%> tr:has(td) input[id*='btnDown']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#<%=dg.ClientID%> tr:last input[id*='btnDown']").attr("disabled", false);
        }
        function SetIndex() {
            $("#<%=dg.ClientID %> tr:has(td)").each(function(index) {
                index++;
                $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(index);
            });
        }
    });
</script>

ASP.NET

<asp:DataGrid ID="dgID" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
            <cc1:ResourceDatagridTempColumn HeaderText="Test">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>'>
                    </asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("B") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </cc1:ResourceDatagridTempColumn>
            <cc1:ResourceDatagridTempColumn HeaderText="Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("C") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
            </cc1:ResourceDatagridTempColumn>
        </Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Move Message">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <input id="btnUp" type="button" value="&uArr;" style="color: Red;" > 
                   <input id="btnDown" type="button" value="&dArr;"              style="color: Red;" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Note: I dont want to sort but to control with custom function..

Any help will be greatly appreciated..